# Circular fisheye distort using opencv3 fisheye model

Tags: opencv3.0, calibration, fisheye

I use a OpenCV [fisheye model](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html) function to perform fisheye calibration work.  My image is a Circular fisheye ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzv4x.jpg)), but I'm getting [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoDos.jpg) from the OpenCV fisheye model function.

I have the following problems:

1. I don't know why the result is an oval and not a perfect circle. Is this as  expected?
2. Can OpenCV fisheye model be calibrated for a Circular fisheye image?
3. I don't understand why the image is not centered when using the cv::fisheye::calibrate function to get the Cx Cy parameter in K?
4. What tips (picture number, angle and position...) can be used on the checkboard to get the corrent camera matrix and Distortion factor?

---

### Expected Result

[image: Fisheye w/ Distortion]

### My Result

[image: Fisheye w/ No Distortion]

Answer (score 1):

First at all cv::fisheye uses a very simple idea. To remove radial distortion it will move points of fisheye circle in direction from circle center to circle edge.
Points near center will be moved a little. Points near edges will be moved on much larger distance.
In other words distance of point movement is not a constant. It's a function f(x)= 1+K1*x3+K2*x5+K3*x7=K4*x9. K1-K4 are coefficients of radial distortion of opencv fisheye undistortion model. In normal case undistorted image is always larger then initial image.
As you can see your undistorted image is smaller then initial fisheye image. I think the source of problem is bad calibration.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know why the result is an oval and not a perfect circle. Is this as  expected?

-> Tangential parameter of the calibration model can make it look like oval. It could be either your actual lens is tilted or calibration is incorrect. Just try to turn off tangential parameter option.

1. Can OpenCV fisheye model be calibrated for a Circular fisheye image?

-> No problem as far as I know. Try ocam as well.

1. I don't understand why the image is not centered when using the cv::fisheye::calibrate function to get the Cx Cy parameter in K?

-> It is normal that optical center does not align with the image center. It is a matter of degree, however. Cx, Cy represents the actual optical center. Low-quality fisheye camera manufactures does not control the quality of this parameter.

1. What tips (picture number, angle and position...) can be used on the checkboard to get the corrent camera matrix and Distortion factor?

-> clear images only, different distances, different angles, different positions. As many as possible.